# Interactive map (non Flash) hover problem

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dictionary, html5-canvas

I've followed this tutorial - http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/ to create a state map of USA which you can see here - http://www.teamworksdesign.com/clients/neurosign/contact/alabama/

I downloaded the source files and got it all working locally then uploaded all the files to the link above. It's almost working but the hover doesn't seem to work when you hover over each state. I had this working locally but cannot work out why it's not working online.

One cause may be that Wordpress (that's what the site is built on) is blocking something along the way.

Can anyone help?

UPDATE:
It's blatantly something clashing with Wordpress as it worked locally, does anyone have any idea's of how to fix it?

Comment: I guess no one can help?

Comment: Did you read the FAQ for that jslib? It may conflict with other scripts used on your site.

Comment: @Eric Thanks, having a quick read has triggered some idea's, as soon as I'm back on the project I'll give it a go.

Comment: According to firebug's net tab the following files are not found (404): maputil.js, mapper.js, wz_jsgraphics.js, cvi_tip_lib.js. Could this be the issue?

Comment: @TJ Ahhhhhh, quite possibly, I'll give it a go, thanks.

Comment: @TJ Thank you thank you thank you. My stupid mistake that's taken weeks to solve!! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to firebug's net tab the following files are not found (404): maputil.js, mapper.js, wz_jsgraphics.js, cvi_tip_lib.js.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you're linking correctly to your js files. Also, your CMS might not like $ symbols - try swapping them all for jQuery instead of the ref symbol... 90% of the time that does it!